# Show Name instead of ID in a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Excuse me if I'm being too much of a beginner but none of the other related answers worker.

**I want to show the category name that the links belong to instead of the id.**

Here's the migration.

```
class CreateCategoriesLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories_links, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :category
  t.references :link
  end
 end

def self.down
  drop_table :categories_links
end
```

end

The categories model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :links
end
```

The links model

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base     
 has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

And here's what's in the links controller under index and show

```
@categories = Category.find(:all, :order => 'name')
```

and here's what's in the index right now but, I've tried every permutation of this that I could find.

```
<%= link.category.name %>
```

If it put `<%= link.category_ids %>`, it'll show the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% link.categories.each do |cat| %>
  <%= cat.name %><br>
<% end %>
```